# Beginner in Python, can't get this for loop to stop

Tags: python, for-loop

```
Bit_128 = 0
Bit_64 = 0
Bit_32 = 0
Bit_64 = 0
Bit_32 = 0
Bit_16 = 0
Bit_8 = 0
Bit_4 = 0
Bit_2 = 0
Bit_1 = 0


Number = int(input("Enter number to be converted: "))

for power in range(7,0,-1):

if (2**power) <= Number:
place_value = 2**power
if place_value == 128:
    Bit_128 = 1
elif place_value == 64:
    Bit_64 = 1
elif place_value == 32:
    Bit_32 = 1
elif place_value == 16:
    Bit_16 = 1
elif place_value == 8:
    Bit_8 = 1
elif place_value == 4:
    Bit_4 = 1
elif place_value == 2:
    Bit_2 = 1
elif place_value ==1:   
    Bit_1 = 1
Number = Number - (place_value)
if Number == 0:
       print ("Binary form of"),Number,("is"),Bit_128,Bit_64,Bit_32,Bit_16,Bit_8,Bit_4,Bit_2,Bit_1
```

I want this loop to move to the next 'power' value when it fails the first if condition, but when I run it in an interpreter, the program keeps on running despite the first condition not being true. I only want it to move on the next conditions if the first condition turns out to be true.
How can I do this? This is my first "big" program in python, and I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Any tips would be appreciated. Btw, the program is meant to convert any number from 1-255 to binary form.

Comment: Because you've pasted your code strangely, the indentation is wrong. This completely changes the behaviour of your code. Please fix it so that we can help you.

Comment: Please correct the indentation of your posted code.

Comment: What 'the program keeps running' means ? It's not an infinite loop, it necessarily stops.

Comment: It should behave like you described if there will be proper indentation. Generally when loop did everything in current iteration it go to next. 
Or you paste it wrongly like @Brandon mentioned.

Comment: FWIW, there are much better ways to do this that don't require a giant `if...elif` block. Hint: use a list for your bits. BTW, Python has a couple of built-in ways to do binary conversion, but I guess this is homework so you can't use those built-ins.

Comment: Thanks guys! The code worked fine, I just had to fix the indentation. Didn't really know about this before so I had to read up a bit to understand the concept, but after fixing everything and making it work, I feel awesome! Thank you again for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a loop to go to the next value, all you need to do is use the continue keyword:

```
...
for power in range(7,0,-1):
    if (2**power) <= Number:
        place_value = 2**power
        continue
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using  "break" statement , to break the current loop when the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Although it's unclear from the code, it doesn't sound like he wants to completely break out of the loop.